# JS/NodeJS JSON Buffer to String

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, buffer

I am truly struggling to convert a Buffer to a string.

For this code

```
let results = await generateRandomNumber(seed);
console.log(results); 
    res.status(200).json({
    "status": 200,
    "number": results
});
```

}

I receive for the console.log(results);

```
   {
  result: <Buffer ee 62 e7 6f c7 4b 7f 57 86 20 bd ba 52 74 4a fc 66 89 70 bb>
}
```

And the response JSON is:

```
{"status":200,"number":{"result":{"type":"Buffer","data":[238,98,231,111,199,75,127,87,134,32,189,186,82,116,74,252,102,137,112,187]}}}
```

All I want to achieve is that the number actually becomes a number and not the Buffer.

Answer (score 1):

There are node [buffer.read < primitive type >](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) functions in documentation ready to use.

Lets take for example `buf.readBigInt64BE([offset])`

```js
const buf = Buffer.from([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff]);
console.log(buf.readBigUInt64BE(0));
```

Your buffer has 20 hex values and if you want convert that into a number im not sure there will be a type to hold such thing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```js
results.toString('utf8')
```

So you can access your json.data f

Comment: This simply returns [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this

```
let results = await generateRandomNumber(seed);
var bufferData = Buffer.from(results);
var resultString = bufferData.toString('utf8');

console.log(results); 
    res.status(200).json({
    "status": 200,
    "number": resultString
});
```